# unable to upload cookbook using knife command

Tags: chef-infra, knife, cookbook

in Windows,Unable to upload cookbook to hosted chef server. my Knife.rd file :

```
# See http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options
current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "xxxxx"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/xxxxx.pem"
validation_client_name   "wis-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/wis-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/xxxx"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks/"]
```

When i run `knife upload learn_chef_apache2` command, getting below error message

> ERROR: Attempt to use relative path 'learn_chef_apache2' when current
>   directory is outside the repository path. ERROR: Current working
>   directory is 'E:/Prasanna_POC/learn_chef'.

I'm running the knife upload command from the path where cookbooks folder present and inside that learn_chef_apache2 cookbook present

Comment: Where is your .chef directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to be running `knife cookbook upload learn_chef_apache2`. The `knife upload` command is more generic and uploads many types of things, but you need to give it the path to the object.

Answer (score 0):

When you run command: `knife upload learn_chef_apache2`, you must make sure cookbook `learn_chef_apache2` inside your `cookbook_path`.

`cookbook_path` set in your `knife.rb` file.

```
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks/"]
```

Please make sure this is : `knife.rb` not `Knife.rd`